# Logout Button Submitting Generates Potentially Dangerous Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a logout button on every page. One page that has a form for editing account information has various text fields for the various account information fields. If a user enters some HTML (such as a 
 tag), and clicks logout, the `Potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client` error. This is probably because the form is submitting, even though it's not submitting to our update function at this point.

How do I handle it so that I can either tell the user that it's a problem, or just strip the HTML?

Comment: Doesn't WebForms have only one "form" for the whole page?  If that's still the case then it doesn't matter which button invokes the submit, the "potentially dangerous request" is being made because form values contain disallowed content.

Comment: Yes that's correct. So how can I remove that content? It doesn't actually make it to the submitting action as it detects the dangerous content and yells about it immediately.

Comment: I guess the user shouldn't submit that content in the first place?  It may be possible to disable that error entirely, but that's probably not advisable.  Maybe there's a way to display a friendlier error message for that particular error?  That would likely require hooking into the application's global error handler at least, since the request never gets as far as a page.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what I'm wondering then. How do I handle it so that I can either tell the user that it's a problem, or just strip the HTML? I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 0):

**This was because .NET detected something in the entered text which looked like an HTML statement.**

To disable request validation, I added the following to the existing "page" directive in that .aspx file.

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

but In .net framework 4.0 you have to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` markup in web.config.

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Suppose I don't want to disable request validation. Is there an easy way to just notify the user when this error is thrown, rather than throw a nasty error message?